# using type synonym causes CS0246 The type or namespace name ... could not be found

Tags: c#, typedef, using, typename, type-synonyms

I've named a type by short synonym.
In next line I try to use this type via its this new short name somehow (doesn't matter):

```
using A = SomeTypeName;
using B = A;
```

But in line 2 the compiler doesn't see the name "A" & generates the error (see in the title).
Why?

Comment: Because it is not allowed. Check out the documention : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx - see the example before last for an example of why the use of an namespace/type alias will not work as part of another alias. The wording is a bit confusing but it is basically saying the compiler tries to resolve the type/namespace A without applying any previously defined aliases in the same compilation unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ECMA-334 9.4.1 Using alias directives** say:

> The order in which using-alias-directives are written has no
>   significance, and resolution of the namespace-or-type-name referenced
>   by a using-alias-directive is not affected by the
>   using-alias-directive itself or by other using-directives in the
>   immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body. *In other
>   words, the namespace-or-type-name of a using-alias-directive is
>   resolved **as if the immediately containing compilation unit or
>   namespace body had no using-directives**.* A using-alias-directive may
>   however be affected by extern-alias-directives in the immediately
>   containing compilation unit or namespace body.